# Can't install SQL SERVER 2017 on Centos 7.4 - mssql-conf setup error

Tags: sql-server, linux, installation, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to install the lastest SQL Server 2017 on a Centos 7.4 VM (Vmware). I get the following error when I try running:

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

using Bash shell.  The error:

> sqlservr: The configuration file '/var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf' failed to load (error: The INI file could not be opened. Errno [2] Filename [mssql.conf]).
>   Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG
>   in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.

I've modified my path, checked permissions and even tried to create the `mssql.conf` file manually by using `mssql-conf setup` and `mssql-conf validate`.

I do not get a log file in `/var/opt/mssql/log` and I've even tried changing the log file location but I still don't get anything.  Has this error been reported before?

Comment: Since CentOS is not officially supported by Microsoft for SQL Server 2017, I don't think you're going to have much joy, I'm afraid. What do you see in the ERRORLOG file?

Comment: Microsoft says it supports RHEL 7.3 & 7.4?   Also, as stated above, I do not get any errorlog

Comment: Nevermind, I installed on another VM without issue.